# Find the tangent plane to $z=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tangent-spaces

I want to find the tangent plane to $z=1$

I'm thinking the normal vektor should be $(0,0,1)$

But how do I get this into an equation of the tangent plane.

Would it be correct to just answer that the tangent plane is exactly $z=1$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That really depends on your definition of “tangent plane.” If you think of it as the best linear approximation to a function in the neighborhood of a point, then the answer should be fairly obvious: you already have a linear function, so it can’t get any better than that.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Consider the one-dimensional case. Which line is tangent to a straight line? Isn't it its own self?

Comment: If I have the line y=x then the tangent line is y=x right? So would it then be a correct answer to say the tangent plane is z=1? :)

Comment: @TomPenny Exactly. There, you got it!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! :) You're the real MVP!!